# Angular programmatically add ngbTooltip on event target doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a tooltip on the clicked elements in my component view, which are mostly svg polygons and paths,
I have tried this function to set the ngbtooltip attribute on the target clicked elements,
but nothing is happening when I click an element and hover on it again, although the clicked element in my inspector appear to have the ngbtooltip attribute added

my View

```
<div class="col py-2" #ngbTooltipp>
    <!-- poc only -->
    <svg-icon (click)="selectSector($event)" [src]="mapPath" [svgStyle]="{ 'width.px':675}"></svg-icon>
  </div>
```

my ts file

```
 public selectSector($event: MouseEvent) {
    // set the tooltip
    let clickedEl = $event.target;
    this.renderer.setAttribute(clickedEl, "ngbtooltip", "hello");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this form https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples#triggers

```html
<div class="col py-2" #ngbTooltipp>
    <!-- poc only -->
    <svg-icon ngbTooltip="You see, I show up on click!" triggers="click:blur" [src]="mapPath" [svgStyle]="{ 'width.px':675}"></svg-icon>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Aman, however the clicked element is not the <svg-icon> itself but a sub element of the svg element (<path>, <polygon>...), so here I need to add the tooltip on the target of the click event

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way

```
<button type="button" ngbTooltip="You see, I show up on click!" >
  Click me!
</button>

<div>
 <ng-containt ngbTooltip="You see, I show up on click!" > Click 
   <svg-icon name="eye" [svgStyle]="{ 'width.px':90 }"></svg-icon>
 </ng-containt> 
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-funyr5?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip-triggers.html

Comment: hanks Siddhartha, but he clicked element is not the <svg-icon> itself but a sub element of the svg element (<path>, <polygon>...), so i would like to add the tooltip using the clicked target programmatically

Comment: you can use <ng-container>  
 <div>
  <ng-containt ngbTooltip="You see, I show up on click!" > Click 
    <svg-icon name="eye" [svgStyle]="{ 'width.px':90 }"></svg-icon>
  </ng-containt> 
</div>